# tensorflow js: Uncaught Error: Error when checking : expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [28,28,1]

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js

I have been trying to implement a MNIST model in the website. I specified input_shape to my first convolutional layer to be of shape (28,28,1) but when i pass a tensor of same shape to the model I get this error asking the input_shape to be (null, 28, 28, 1).
This is my tensor preprocessing code:

```
 let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img).resizeNearestNeighbor([28,28]).toFloat();
 const rgb = tf.tensor1d([0.2989, 0.587, 0.114])
 tensor = tf.sum(tensor.mul(rgb), 2).expandDims(2)
```

Here the value of tensor.shape is [28,28,1]. The tensor generated is :

```
t {isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(3), dtype: "float32", size: 784, strides: Array(2), …}
```

This is the model summary:

```
    Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               1179776   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,198,721
Trainable params: 1,198,721
Non-trainable params: 0
___________________________________________________
```

Here is the line from my model.json:

```
"class_name": "Conv2D",
        "config": {
          "name": "conv2d",
          "trainable": true,
          "batch_input_shape": [
            null,
            28,
            28,
            1
          ],
```

The Error is :

```
errors.ts:48 Uncaught Error: Error when checking : expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [28,28,1]
at new e (errors.ts:48)
at Md (training.ts:312)
at e.predict (training.ts:1069)
at e.predict (models.ts:766)
at predict (index.js:68)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):34)
```

Answer (score 0):

The tensor should be a 4d tensor. By expanding the dimension of the tensor the first time, the output is a 3d tensor. After the sum, the output is a 2d. So the tensor needs to be expanded twice or tell the sum operation to keep the initial dimension.

```
tensor = tf.sum(tensor.mul(rgb), 2).expandDims(2).expandDims()
// or
tensor = tf.sum(tensor.mul(rgb), 2, true).expandDims()
```

The other solution would be to use reshape

```
tensor = tf.sum(tensor.mul(rgb), 2).reshape([1, 28, 28, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution by @edkeveked,

```
const rgb = tf.tensor1d([0.2989, 0.587, 0.114])
```

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29)